# Errors when importing python modules

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I got the following error when I compiled as followed. Why the errors? Thanks in advance.

```
cd /root/rel_path/ctlib/src 
python3 main_prog.py
```

### Error:

```
root@Linux:~/rel_path/ctlib/src# python3 main_prog.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_prog.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ctlib.auto import CtAuto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ctlib'
root@Linux:~/rel_path/ctlib/src
```

### Example path tree:

```
/root/rel_path/
             |--- ctlib
                     |--- src
                            |--- main_prog.py
                     |--- auto
                            |--- __init__.py
```

Code:

### main_prog.py code:

```
from ctlib.auto import CtAuto

print("hello")
```

### **init**.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class CtAuto:
    def print_hello(self):
        print("Hello, from CtAuto")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is actually looking for the CtAuto class in auto.py which does not exist in your tree:

```
/root/rel_path/
             |--- ctlib
                     |--- src
                            |--- main_prog.py
                     |--- auto
                            |--- __init__.py
                     |--- auto.py
```

Use `from ctlib.auto.auto import CtAuto` instead and put your CtAuto class in `/root/rel_path/ctlib/auto/auto.py`

**[EDIT]**
Because you `__main__` is in a subdirecory you need to add the rootdir of the project to the `Pythonpath`. (before importing `CtAuto`)

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../')
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/root/rel_path/')
```

Comment: Still didn't work. Errors:  
root@Linux:~/rel_path/ctlib/src# python3 main_prog.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_prog.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ctlib.auto.auto import CtAuto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ctlib'
root@Linux:~/rel_path/ctlib/src#

Comment: Sorry, I missread your question. Updated my Post. Now it is working for me locally.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me too. Found temporary change to PYTHONPATH environment variable is OK too:

export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/root/rel_path/"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running the program in sub-level (child) and doing import at the same level without creating any packages, which is a relative import on the same level.

Changing the main_prog.py like below will make it work.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from auto import CtAuto

print("hello")
```